# Redefine ArcGIS Krovak projection for MapInfo

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

I have an ArcGIS datum/projection (as below) and trying to write as a line into the Mapinfow.prj. Problem is that the MapInfo documentation for Krovak does not match the ArcGIS description - either in number or name of parameters (lesser number of parameters in MapInfo) 
Was hoping for a line for Mapinfow.prj which incorporates the following…..

```
GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",
DATUM["D_GDA_1994",
SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Krovak"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",253276.6182],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",1295660.263],
PARAMETER["Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1",78.5],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0003],
PARAMETER["Azimuth",105.74038],
PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",120.531377],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",-27.24038],
PARAMETER["X_Scale",1.0],
PARAMETER["Y_Scale",-1.0],
PARAMETER["XY_Plane_Rotation",259.05],
UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: Comparing with https://epsg.io/5513, I don't see a sense in the CRS you want to create for Australia instead of the Czech Republic and Slovakia. Rotating by an angle can be done with an oblique mercator projection.

Comment: That's an Esri-style prj file. We use the  X_Scale/Y_Scale/XY_Plane_Rotation parameters to set the axes directions AKA whether to use south-west or east-north. Because MapInfo doesn't list anything, they may be supporting the south-west version only. Not a post-projection rectification.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that MapInfo Pro v15.2 comes with these three Krowak projections:

```
"--- Krovak Coordinate Systems ---"
"S-JTSK (Krovak) Coordinate system - Updated\p5514", 32, 1024, 7, 24.833333333333, 49.5, 78.5, 30.288139722222, 0, 0
"JTSK03 for Slovak Republic", 32, 1025, 7, 24.833333333333, 49.5, 78.5, 30.288139722222, 0, 0
"S-JTSK (Krovak) Coordinate system\p102067", 32, 1020, 7, 42.5, 49.5, 78.5, 30.28813972, 0, 0
```

Projection type 32 is "Krovak Oblique Conformal Conic (JTSKc)".
As parameters, this projection type takes these:

- Datum: 116 (GDA 94)
- Units: 7 (Meters) (Degrees?)
- Origin, Longitude: 120.531377
- Origin, Latitude: -27.24038
- Standard Parallel 1: 78.5
- Azimuth: 105.74038
- Scale Factor: 1.0003
- False Easting: 253276.6182
- False Northing: 1295660.263

So it could look like this

```
"S-JTSK / Krovak\p5513", 32, 116, 7, 120.531377, -27.24038, 78.5, 105.74038, 1.0003, 253276.6182, 1295660.263
```

Let me try to verify this as I can see we do have a number of other/similar datums which are used in the projections already in the projection file:
 - 1020: S-JTSK (Ferro prime meridian)
 - 1024: Not described
 - 1025: Not described

Comment: did you ever verify the situation?

Comment: Should be okay but I would recommend that you give it a try with some know coordiantes to test it. Also notice that GDA94 is identical to multiple other datums such as NAD83, EUREF89, GRS80, etc. so it's a bit weird using a "Australian" datum like GDA94 for a European coordinate system...